# ServiceStack with IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0, servicestack

I installed Clean Windows Web Server 2008 R2 64-bit with IIS 7.5. I created .NET v4.0 application pool and Web Site in this pool, where I deployed my application with ServiceStack services.
I got this error message in web browser when I opened servicestack page.:

```
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "ServiceStack.Factory" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list.
```

My application is working in Visual studio hosted IIS server.
Can be problem with IIS 7.5 instalation and servicestack or it is some asp.net issue?

Comment: Are you using classic or integrated pipeline mode in IIS?

Comment: I tried both. But default I use integrated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1) Ensure the following is in the web.config

```
<!-- Required for IIS 7.0 -->
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add path="*" 
         name="ServiceStack.Factory"
         type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" 
         verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"
         resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

copied from http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/

2) If still not working then try running this command

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

See the article in comments that vaclamar found.

Comment: Yes, I do. Application is running from Visual Studio hosted IIS.

Comment: Have you tried running "aspnet_regiis.exe -i" on the server under the v4.0.30319 folder or whatever your asp.net version # is?

Comment: Yes, that's my problem. Thanks for help. Now it is working. I found also this good  [article](http://wishmesh.com/2010/08/iis-7-5-error-handler-pagehandlerfactory-integrated-has-a-bad-module-managedpipelinehandler-in-its-module-list/) about it.

Comment: In (non-server) Windows 8, you have to turn on ASP.NET under IIS in "Turn Windows Features On or Off"