# ServiceStack.Factor has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, servicestack

I have written an API using ServiceStack to retrieve documents from my SharePoint document library and I am using MVC to output the result.

However when I try and run my application I am receiving a HTTP error:

> 500.21 ServiceStack.Factor has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list error

I am running my application in classic mode in IIS as I need to use impersonation to authenticate with my SharePoint server.

There seems to be a difficulty with using ServiceStack in classic mode.

How can I resolve this error?

I hope this makes sense.

Any help will be appreciated

Here is my configuration:

```
<system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
            <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
            <handlers>
                <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="classicMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
```

Update:

Running my application as a different user on my dev machine works fine the issue seems to be a difference between IIS and the ASP.NET Development Server

Comment: I have also tried the suggestions in this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030418/servicestack-with-iis-7-5  But with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think classic mode can handle the route configurations. As stated here - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs - You do need to perform additional configuration when using IIS 7.0 in classic mode or use a file extension that gets mapped to ASP.NET framework (aspx, axd, ashx).

I was able to get classic mode working against IIS 7 using the below configurations

web.config (partial and using preCondition="integratedMode"):

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <add path="servicestack*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" 
             verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

And I added .aspx to my routes in order to hit ASP.NET (I would imagine you could us the other solutions listed in the link above as well)

```
Routes
.Add<Hello>("/hello.aspx")
.Add<Hello>("/hello.aspx/{Name}");
```

I can make requests to `http://localhost/hello.aspx and http://localhost/hello.aspx?name=Test`

**Update 1**

It turns out I can remove all the IIS 7 (`<system.webServer>`) elements when running in classic mode. My entire web.config is below. What is the **path** attribute for your `<httpHandlers>` element? Perhaps you are getting a 404 because the **path** is different?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="servicestack*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment Answers:

**Therefore, is this functionally equivalent to path="api*" as in your example?**

No. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx 
Take a look at Section 2 here: http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/ The `<httpHandler>` element has the path attribute for a custom path.

Also, use IIS Express as your development server in Visual Studio. You should be able to simulate the IIS 7 classic mode issues that don't occur within the standard development server. http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=IISExpress

Comment: Thanks for your help. We already have the routing "wired up", so to speak so apologies for not making that clear.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We already have the routing "wired up", so to speak so apologies for not making that clear.   

Your configuration **is** interesting, however. Why are you using a `precondition` of `integratedMode` within Classic mode?   

We have tried this and we get a 404 - interestingly, ServiceStack redirects us to the `metadata` page - which fails as the /metadata path isn't supported in Classic Mode.  

Perhaps there is opportunity here?  

Thanks for your help thusfar :)

_Sorry for repeat, SO refuses to allow us to keep the comment open as we research._

Comment: Updated my answer based on new results.

Comment: Thanks. We've just check and we have the path specified as "*", **but**, this is in a `location` element beneath the `api` path. Therefore, is this functionally equivalent to `path="api*"` as in your example? More detail is that we can get to ServiceStack's web front-end fine on the ASP.NET dev server, it is just IIS 7.x that is causing us this issue.

Comment: Updated answer in response to question above

Comment: Thanks. We have just tested on ASP NET Dev server, IISEXPRESS and IIS 7. The application works fine in both integrated mode & classic mode on ASP NET Dev server & IISEXPRESS. The application 'works' without passing through the authentication using integrated mode on IIS. However as soon as you switch to classic mode in IIS the application stops working and we get:Handler "ServiceStack.Factory" has a bad module. We should also add that this is an IIS Error (Blue background) rather than a .NET error.

Comment: These - https://gist.github.com/paaschpa/5100697 - are the web.configs I've been testing with while using the ServiceStack.Hello example. I may not be recreating your exact error.

Comment: Thanks @user1901853, you've been really helpful. We haven't quite solved the issue but your help as confirmed our suspicions. Through more testing, our requirement to use classic mode impacts our routing, which means we have to manually bind ISAPIs, which then (for some reason) impacts ServiceStack. Everything works fine in Integrated Mode, but authentication doesn't happen. We're switching to Web API to see if that works out better.

Comment: Good Luck - I've had good success with Web API as well(though never tried against Classic mode). Programming is hard :) http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/29/programming-is-hard.aspx